# C# access Database update from texbox

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

I am working on a database project, a huge part of the program is done but stuck with a problem.
I have a DB named employee, I search with emp_ID in a textbox and get the attributes(Name, Surname) from DB and write them to another textbox. When I click to save button I want it to update the Name and Surname from the textbox. Here is my code looks fine but does not work.
Pseudocode: Update Name and Surname from table Employee where ID = emp_ID

The Error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

My Code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             String id = searchTB.Text;
             string Name = nametb.Text;
             using (var connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Employee.accdb"))
             using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
             {
                 command.CommandText = "select *from Employee where [emp_ID]= " + id + " ";
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", int.Parse(nametb.Text));
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Surname", int.Parse(surnametb.Text));
                 connection.Open();
                 var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                 while (reader.Read())
                 {
                     nametb.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();
                     surnametb.Text = reader["Surname"].ToString();
                 }

             }
}
```

Comment: For a start, need a space after * in SQL statement. Don't need to concatenate space at end. If emp_ID is a number type, possibly id should not be declared as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things need to be changed:

1. `String id = searchTB.Text;` to be `string id = searchTB.Text;`
2. `"select *from` to be `"select * from`
3. `"select *from Employee where [emp_ID]= " + id + " "` to be `where emp_Name = @Name and emp_Surname = @Surname` as you search by name and surname.
4. `"Name", int.Parse(nametb.Text)` you can not Parse name to integer
5. sql statement should be secure enough to prevent the **SQL injection**.
6. The variables could be better named if camelCase (read about camelCase and PascalCase naming)

Finally, it is wrong to use the same button to search and edit (Read about **SRP principle** of **SOLID**)

So, Initially, you need something like the codes below (I did not test it as I do not have Access but looks good).

*Note that I do not know about your Database so you should put the right names of fields*

**For Query Side:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Search Button -- Query
    
    string name = nameTb.Text;
    string surName = surNameTb.Text;
    
    var connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Employee.accdb");
    var query = new OleDbCommand("select emp_ID, emp_Name, emp_Surname from Employee where emp_Name = @Name, emp_Surname = @Surname", connection);
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", surName);

    connection.Open();

    OleDbDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            idTb.Text = reader["emp_ID"].ToString();   //<<=== this is the primary key that never updated
            nameTb.Text = reader["emp_Name"];
            surNameTb.Text = reader["emp_Surname"];
        }
    }
    
    connection.Close();
    reader.Close();
    query.Dispose();
}
```

**For Update Command Side (Another Button):**

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Update Button -- Command

    string id = idTb.Text;
    string name = nameTb.Text;
    string surName = surNameTb.Text;

    var connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Employee.accdb");
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("update Employee set emp_Name = @Name, emp_Surname = @Surname where emp_ID = @Id", connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", surName);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    connection.Close();
    command.Dispose();

}
```

While you Learn, Have a good start :)